# Round numbers and keep Scientific Notation in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I'm looking to round to two decimal places as it is currently at 16.  I have this done like this;

```
##rounding numbers

p32_us1rounding = read.csv("p32_us1_ff6.csv")

#print(p32_us1rounding)

dfp32_us1 = data.frame(p32_us1rounding[-1])

dfp32_us1 <- round(dfp32_us1, digits = 2)

write.csv(dfp32_us1, "32 Fama French for US Market on or before 01-08-2005.csv")
```

This works perfectly but there are a few rows where I have an extremely small number which I would like to keep in scientific notation.  For example the first column of the 8th row is `7.12206157653355e-67`.  This obviously rounds down to zero but I would like it to say `7.12E-67`.  Is there anyway to do this while also having the other numbers rounded?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample data set?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert the numbers to character strings to use different formatting. Then just use the `quote=FALSE` argument in `write.csv` to prevent them from being surrounded by quotation marks:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(100)*100/39
x <- matrix(x, 10, 10)
y <- ifelse(x > .1, sprintf("%.2f", x), sprintf("%.2e", x))
write.csv(y, "Test.csv", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
cat(readLines("Test.csv", 4), sep="\n")
# V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10
# 2.35,1.17,2.32,1.89,0.97,0.85,1.73,0.11,1.49,1.71
# 2.40,1.84,0.36,2.08,1.12,0.89,2.52,0.36,0.40,6.13e-04
# 0.73,2.40,2.54,1.00,9.60e-02,1.02,1.95,0.55,0.92,0.53
```

Last value in line 2 is in scientific notation and the 5th value in line 3.